# Is it possible to ignore a specific locale for translation with lint in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, translation, lint

As the title says I'm looking to ignore specific locales from the `MissingTranslation` lint error in Android Studio. Here's the reason behind this question:

I have multiple Android Studio projects for specific applications. All of these applications reference one or more modules from a shared library project that contains common code, resources, etc.

The shared modules contain common code, widgets, resources, and strings that are used across all the other applications. The problem is that my shared modules have translations for more languages than my applications so the applications complain that application specific strings are not translated in the additional languages included in the shared modules.

I have a feeling that if I built the shared modules as libraries and referenced them that way, rather than referencing the code directly in the application projects, this error would go away. However when I am working in an application I am often modifying code in the shared libraries as well so it is much more efficient to reference the code directly rather than a built module.

I am also aware that I can disable the `MissingTranslation` entirely but I would like to be aware that an application specific string is not translated in a locale that application supports.

Comment: The lint error is correct - users will see a partially translated app if your shared module is translated but your app is not. Are you trying to strip out specific languages entirely from individual apps (so that users consistently see an untranslated app for a specific language)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I understand the error is correct. The issue is that I'm a one man team who has to pay for translations so I only translate a given app based on need. However common, non-application specfic, strings get put into the library. So my library might have strings for 10 locales but a specific app might only be translated for 5. I'm ok if the common strings get translated for a locale the app doesn't completely support. What I'm looking to eliminate is my application strings now warning my that every string is missing a translation for the library locales. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `MissingTranslation` Lint warning will always appear if there is a chance that users will see a partially translated app.

Therefore, you have two choices:

1. Limit languages only to those you specifically support by [removing unused alternative resources](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#unused-alt-resources) (thus removing the translated strings from your library project for unsupported languages):

```
    android {
        defaultConfig {
            ...
            resConfigs "en", "fr"
        }
    }
```

2. Suppressing the `MissingTranslation` warning.

Comment: Sweet, `resConfigs` is exactly what I'm looking for !